# How can I prevent mod_authz_ldap from using login credentials to bind to LDAP

Tags: apache, authentication, ldap

I am trying to use mod_authz_ldap for user authentication. Have a strange LDAP setup where, we have to bind to the LDAP directory as

```
uid=user,o=organisation
```

then query

```
cn=xxx,o=organisation
```

to get the credentials of the user. The following configuration actually works, *except* that it attempts to use the credentials of the user logging in to bind to the LDAP directory, which needless to say fails.

To validate this, I tried to authenticate to the application as our LDAP bind user and the authentication succeeds.

```
<Location />

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My LDAP authenticated app"

    AuthzLDAPLogLevel debug

    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthBasicAuthoritative off
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off

    AuthzLDAPBindPassword bindpass
    AuthzLDAPBindDN "uid=binduser,o=my.edu.au"

    AuthzLDAPMethod ldap
    AuthzLDAPServer ldapdevel.my.edu.au
    AuthzLDAPUserBase o=my.edu.au
    AuthzLDAPUserKey cn
    AuthzLDAPUserScope base
    AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute cn

    Require valid-user

</Location>
```

Apache error log to demonstrate that mod_authz_ldap is attempting to bind as the user attempt to authenticate agains the app:

```
[Fri Sep 07 14:14:27 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] [15628] bind as cn=devraj,l=X,ou=Students,o=my.edu.au failed: 49
[Fri Sep 07 14:14:27 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] [15628] basic LDAP authentication of user 'devraj' failed
[Fri Sep 07 14:14:27 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] access to / failed, reason: verification of user id 'devraj' not configured
```

Also if I provide incorrect bind credentials mod_authz_ldap complains about not being able to bind as the bind user. This suggests that it tries to bind as the bind user, but also binds as the authenticating user.

My Question, what am I doing wrong that's causing mod_auz_ldap to use the users credentials to bind to the LDAP directory?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Why is  AuthzLDAPBindDN "uid=binduser,o=my.edu.au"?
Then you show AuthzLDAPUserKey cn.

The "uid=binduser,o=my.edu.au" should typically, be a valid user from LDAP and usually a service account.

Then the AuthzLDAPUserKey cn would represent the RDN (Relative Distinguished Name) attribute of users in LDAP. It would be non-typical for you to have a user uid=binduser and other users to be like: cn=devraj.

Does uid=binduser,o=my.edu.au exist?

Does the user cn=devraj,l=X,ou=Students,o=my.edu.au exist?
(or is it: uid=devraj,l=X,ou=Students,o=my.edu.au)

-jim

Comment: the ldap setup is strange (not my design) have to bind as uid=binduser,o=... and then query for cn=xx. Both those user accounts do exists in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

> it attempts to use the credentials of the user logging in to bind to the LDAP directory, which needless to say fails

Why 'needless to say'? And why does it fail at all? This is exactly what it is supposed to do. Normally you should be searching the directory for the user, possibly using a system account to do so, then binding as the found user with his credentials. If that succeeds, authentication is complete. If your LDAP isn't set up to support that, it is set up wrongly.

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: @Devraj So what's your question?

Comment: from what you've said, it would seem the LDAP directory I am dealing with is setup incorrectly.

Comment: @Devraj I should restate. More accurately, someone is confused as to how to use LDAP.

Comment: agree completely, trouble obviously is I am trying to fit into someone else's environment. Thanks for your time.